# Outlook Unresolved recipients

Tags: email

For two days all of my Outlook emails are going into my outbox.  I am receiving a message that says I have "unresolved recipients." I have read all the comments about this that I can find and each one says that I must be sending to an improperly formatted email address. I checked the email addresses of all the recipients of the emails I am trying to send and am convinced they are correct.  I did a test and tried to send an email to myself. Even that email comes up as an unresolved recipient even though I am using the same address I've used for 4 years my own business Outlook address.  Can you help me resolve this problem please?

Comment: Is this a problem on a Mac? Have you tried it on a different pc? Could it be a problem with Outlook?

Comment: Yah, I would delete the mail server settings and set up again. Especially if you tested with an email with just your own email address in it.